# Can't get content provider on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I use the [TelegramGallery](https://github.com/TangXiaoLv/TelegramGallery) library. I have some problems with `ContentProvider`. I created a lib for getting images from a gallery or something else. It works well and returns the path for the images list, but when I want to get URI for every image, the app throws

> Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/0000-0000/TropicBeauty Austin/Screenshot_20170905-184459.jpg

The problem is with this piece of code:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ArrayList<String> fullMediaPath = new ArrayList<>();
    if(resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == Const.OPEN_ATTACH_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE){
        ArrayList<String> photos = (ArrayList<String>) data.getSerializableExtra(GalleryActivity.PHOTOS);
        fullMediaPath.addAll(photos);
        if(photos != null && photos.size()>0) {
            try {
                for (String photo : photos) {
                    File file = new File(photo);
                    Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                    uriPhotos.add(path);
                }
```

This exception happens only on Samsung devices on Android 7.0 and I can't reproduce this crash. My `provider_path.xml`

```xml
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_p"
        path="."/>
    <files-path
        name="files_p"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="ext_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache_p"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache_p"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

The code of set data in the intent

```java
@Override
public void didSelectPhotos(ArrayList<String> photos, ArrayList<String> captions) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(PHOTOS, photos);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

Maybe I didn't write the correct path or name, but on any other devices, it works great. What is the problem with Samsung, I don't know. Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: where did you get `photos` array/list from?

Comment: @pskink see my edit question

Comment: so the gallery activity returns list of files and not list of `Uri`s?

Comment: @pskink yes. I create uri with this line FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

Comment: @pskink for example it's the full path in photo value /storage/emulated/0/test/email_2.png and this is uri in path value content://com.mybubblzinc.mybubblz.provider/external_p/test/email_2.png

Comment: @pskink. A lib return correct path and I think the problem not in a lib. The exception said Failed to find configured root. The problem with path settings or I am wrong?

Comment: most likely you are calling `getUriForFile` with a `File` which is not hosted by your `FileProvider`

Comment: @pskink I think the same but maybe you know the solution. Did I write all paths in my provider_path.xml or maybe I miss something

Comment: so what gallery are you using? what is the intent you use in `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: @pskink see my edit question